# Does TFS 2013 build supports VS 2012 solutions?

Tags: build, msbuild, continuous-integration

I have a solution created in VS2012 recently moved to TFS2013 Express. When I try to define a build in Team Explorer 2013 and select the solution TFS returns following issues:

```
Parameter 1. Projects: cannot convert value '$/[MY SOLUTION PATH AND NAME].sln' of type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.StringList to type System.String[], reset to default.

Parameter 2. Configurations: cannot convert value 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.PlatformConfigurationList' of type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.PlatformConfigurationList to type System.String[], reset to default.
```

When I create a build from VS 2012 - I have problems with setting up automatic tests:

```
The parameter AutomatedTests could not be loaded because the type InArgument<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter[]> was not found.
The parameter AdvancedTestSettings could not be loaded because the type InArgument<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter> was not found.
The parameter AdvancedBuildSettings could not be loaded because the type InArgument<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter> was not found.
The parameter AgentSettings could not be loaded because the type InArgument<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter> was not found.
The member Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.ProcessParameterMetadata.ValueFormatString for parameter Metadata could not be loaded because no such member exists.
```

I'm using TfvsTemplate.12.xaml template

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are using VS2013 to create your build definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error when creating a NEW build definition, make sure you select the default Build Controller. Unless the Build Controller is set, the script does not know where the Custom Assemblies resides within TFS.

I wasted half a day figuring that out. Once I selected the default build controller the DLL was loaded and the error/warning went away.